# How to delete file from SDcard when uninstalling the application

Tags: android, sd-card, uninstallation

I have application that record a sound, I want to delete this sound file when uninstalling this application. how is that possible ?

Comment: you cannot remove file from sdcard when uninstalling the application.You have to explicitly remove folder or file...but if you have stored the file in the internal storage it will remove when  uninstalling the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should store the files in the internal storage. Thus, when the application is removed, so are the files.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to saved the file so it can be deleted upon uninstall

1. on the SD-card: 
   in an app only file note that it is deleted automatically only on API 8 and above.

// find or create private file need to be in a Context object

```
File root_private_SD_Card_file = getExternalFilesDir(null); 

File myOwnFile = getExternalFilesDir("MyOwnFile") //
```

`String path = myOwnFile.getAbsolutePath()`

this method also hides the image video and audio files from other applications

2.
by storing directly to the device's storage from within a context

```
openFileInput(fileName);
```

[android developer's link][1]

This method can be problematic because device storage can be limited or occupied.

Answer (score 0):

If the `minSdk` of your application is `8` you can use

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

as the doc stands:

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the external filesystem
>   (that is somewhere on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) where
>   the application can place persistent files it owns. These files are
>   private to the applications, and not typically visible to the user as
>   media.

When you uninstall the application, the related directory would be deleted (tipically the root would be `com.yourdomain.yourappname`).

If you have a Samsung phone with Android ICS, that does not work (I think it is a bug)